# Why are Mongoose documents not plain JavaScript objects by default?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose

When returning Mongoose documents from a MongoDB database, you can't just edit the returned document. You either need to convert it to a plain JavaScript object by the [`.toObject()`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html#toObject) function - which has yet to work for me - or `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(doc))` it.

My question is why is this the case? Why aren't they just returned as plain, simple, easy to use JavaScript objects by default?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Because Mongoose documents have additional functionality, like various [built-in and custom instance methods](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html#methods). It allows you to call `document.save(...)` after changing a document, for instance.

If you want your queries to return plain objects, you can also use the [`lean`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#query_Query-lean) option.